# H.264 - Identify Access Units of an image

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I need to parse a H.264 stream to collect only NAL's needed to form a complete image, of only one frame. I'm reading the H.264 standard, but it's confuse and hard to read. I made some experiments but, did not worked. For example, i extracted an access unit with primary_pic_type == 0 containing only slice_type == 7 (I-Slice), it should give me a frame, but i tried to extract from ffmpeg, it did not work. But, when i append the next access_unit, containing only slice_type == 5 (P-Slice) it worked. Maybe i need to extract POC information, but i think not, because i only need extract one frame, but i'm not sure. Someone have some tip of how get only NAL's i need to form one complete image?

Comment: How are you extracting the image? CLI, API?

Comment: From a MPEG Transport (.ts) DVB Tune

Comment: How are you extracting the image? CLI, API?

Comment: Oh, sorry, from ffmpeg: 

ffmpeg -i infile -frames:v 1 output.jpg

Comment: For raw dump: `ffmpeg -i in -vframes 1 -map 0:v -f data frame1.raw`. For Annex B: `ffmpeg -i in -vframes 1 frame1.h264`

Comment: But, i need to filter the minimum NALS's necessary from the raw bitstream to send to the server to extract with ffmpeg. I'm getting the bitsretam from an embedded system with i poor hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem, i solved it. I go until i find an AUD of primary_pic_type == 0. So i extract the AUD and the next one (when it's a field), send the two AUD to the server, and decode the frame using ffmpeg to generate a JPG image.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an "Annex B" style stream that looks like this:

(AUD)(SPS)(PPS)(I-Slice)(PPS)(P-Slice)(PPS)(P-Slice) ... (AUD)(SPS)(PPS)(I-Slice)

I assume that you want to decode a single I frame and we hope that your I frame is also an IDR frame.

Your are somewhere in the middle of the stream.

Keep reading until your find an (AUD) = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x09.

Now push everything into your decoder until you are in front of | marking the second (PPS) : (AUD)(SPS)(PPS)(I-Slice) | (PPS)

Flush your decoder to emit an uncompressed frame.

This doesn't solve the general case but probably decodes most well behaved streams.

Comment: Yes, i did that, but did not work, let me show you an example:

Comment: Yes, i did that, but did not work, in one case did, but another, not.
1) First i founded an AUD with primary_pic_type == 0 (Init of I only), so i have: (AUD) (SPS) (PPS) (I-Slice) ... (I-Slice)
Ok, i run ffmpeg and did not work, so i kept going going, and the next, i had:(AUD)(SPS)(PPS)(P-Slice)(P-Slice) ... (P-SLice), and wueh i put both together: (AUD) (SPS) (PPS) (I-Slice) ... (I-Slice) (AUD)(SPS)(PPS)(P-Slice)(P-Slice) ... (P-SLice) it worked.

Comment: Can you share the stream?

Comment: I filtered splitting in each AUD sequentially: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QBeqyxK_WL83TFNVlCIXSbwmQFdF1FCJ/view?usp=sharing